# Not able to use execute php in my rule in hosted environment

Tags: drupal, rules

I use a drupal 7 installation. On my localhost dev environment i had no trouble importing rules.
Now that i am on a hosting environment i am not able to import a certain rule using "execute php".
I am also unable to create the rule myself pasting the php code in particular action.

Once i paste the code and hit save the page just skips back asking for the action to add.

Leaving me with no error messages or what so ever

What am i missing here.

Is it a lack of permissions on my hosted environment?

Comment: Many hosting companies prevent use of `exec` on shared hosting, which is required for the `execute php` to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this requires exec as per ceejayoz's comment. Check that the "PHP filter" module is enabled in your module list.

Comment: Yes it is enabled and permission set as well.
The install on my hosting is a clone of my local dev install.

Comment: It was indeed my hosting company who was preventing the use of php exec